# Node.js + Express - CSS Loading in Google Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: css, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, express

I am new to NodeJS/Express and I am developing a simple server app that updates a clock in the client window. I had been developing using Chrome and everything was working great. However, when I tried the app later in Firefox, I noticed that none of the CSS rules were applied. I looked at the 'network' tab in the Firefox debugger screen and confirmed that the browser is successfully getting the CSS file. So my question is, why does the CSS load properly on Chrome and not on Firefox? A work around is fine, but I am also interested in understanding what is going on here, or what I am doing wrong.

Please note that the CSS file lives at ./public/css/link-server.css
Here is my code (I am also open to general improvements in my nodejs/express code and organization):

#### link-server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var AIN_PATH = '/sys/devices/ocp.3/44e0d000.tscadc/tiadc/iio:device0'

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/link-server.html');
});

function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}

setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours   = date.getHours();
    var minutes = pad(date.getMinutes());
    var seconds = pad(date.getSeconds());
    var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    io.sockets.emit('timer', { time: timeString });
    //console.log(timeString);
}, 1000);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected to client.');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });
});

http.listen(2000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:2000');
});
```

#### link-server.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web Interface</title>
    <link href="/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="/css/link-server.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/-css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
        <img id="link-logo" src="/images/link-logo.png"/>
        <div id="time" class="roboto">00:00:00</div>
    </div>
  </body>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('timer', function (data) {
        var counter = document.getElementById('time');
        counter.innerHTML = data.time;
    }); 
</script>
</html>
```

#### link-server.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("Roboto-Regular.ttf"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("Roboto-Regular.ttf"); }

.roboto {
    font-family: "Roboto";
}

body {
    margin:             0px;
}

#header {
    padding-top:        10px;
    padding-bottom:     10px;
    min-width:          1000px;
    background-color:   #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom:      1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#link-logo {
    width:              100px;
    margin-left:        70px;
}

#time {
    display:        inline-block;
    margin-left:    50px;
    color:          black;
    color:          #6b6e71;
    font-size:      11pt;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the `<link>` element's `type` attribute is incorrect?

Comment: Wow, that was it. I feel dumb. Thanks for the quick answer!